# Is it possible to manage own memory pages for program?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I'm going into distributed programming and I'm thinking about possible ways of sharing data to multiple computers.

Assume: I'll manage memory coherence by proper task management (only one writing task to a memory region, or one or multiple tasks reading from same memory). Together with custom page management - which I'm asking about in this question.

I would like to work with pointers directly for least overhead (no processing of shared data - index/pointer rewrite, ,... ). Also I would like to lazy load memory pages / shared data / on first access.

So it is possible to manage memory pages:

- allocate precisely specified memory range (no data processing, pointer rewritting)
- use custom function/callback, when memory page is missed - loads data from network
- force system to remove page from memory. This should cause page miss on next access to same memory page
- optional: not remove page, but mark is "unsafe" - custom function has to check it, whether some else machine modified that region (don't transfer it again, if not needed)

*Assume x64-64bit architecture is used, and I only care about Linux OS (for now).*

Comment: I haven't tried at all, but I think you can set a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`, then map the page in the signal handler. You might need another thread to actually load the data though.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Well, I thoung `SIGSEGV` is access to unmapped or unallowed memory space.. However, I want to catch proper memory access, but missed. I'm thinking, whether some kernel driver won't be needed for that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by 'missed' pages - pages that are mapped but not in memory yet? What exactly are you mapping?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Well, I've done more research on that topic. It looks like that I'm looking for a way to override virtual address to physical address translation for process. So I'll hide distributed memory management from normal execution. Also, I'll load stuff on-demand and don't add overhead to each pointer dereferencing, since CPU has TLB which can be utilized for this purpose.